# Using transaction on the database is creating and quickly deleting data at the given path

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been learning and got some grip over firebase for a while now.

I am building a blog posts webapp (provided in official firebase examples) as a learning example;

I want to also add custom notifications system so that users can view notifications when logged in.

Whenever a user likes or comments on a blog post a data path is created under the post's author uid node as follows:

```
 --user-notifications
 ----uid1
 --------postid
 ------------notif: 'notification text'
 ------------postId: postId
 ------------viewed: false
 ------------createdAt: 'some date'
 ----uid2
 --------postid
 ------------notif: 'notification text'
 ------------postId: postId
 ------------viewed: false
 ------------createdAt: 'some date'
```

Instead of sending a seperate notification for every like or comment I wanted to implement facebook's type of notification where all the likes for a particular post comes in a single notification . For example: *john, kate and others liked your post* or *jane, todd and others commented on your post*.

For this mentioned scenario I am using transactions as follows:

```
 var sendCustomNotification = function(fromUID, recieverUID, userName, actionText, postID){
    const ref = firebase.database().ref("user-notifications/" + recieverUID + "/" + postID);
     if(fromUID !== recieverUID){
         ref.transaction(function(obj){
             if(obj){
                 //if notification is not viewd by the user 
                 if(obj.viewed){
                     obj.notif = userName + actionText;
                     obj.viewed = false; 
                 }else{
                 //if notification is viewd by the user the the user's names gets added into one
                     obj.notif = userName + ' and more ' + actionText;
                 }
             }else{
                ref.set({
                    notif: userName +  '  '' + actionText,
                    statusId: postID,
                    viewed: false,
                    createdAt: formatDate(new Date())
                }); 
             }
             return obj;
         })
     }
 };
```

I use this `sendCustomNotification()` inside the code where the user comments or likes the post

**now the problem is:**

When a user comments or likes the `sendCustomNotification()` is called and in the realtime database a node is created or updated as expected but it gets deleted immediately again.

Dont't know what is the reaaon for this behaviour

Comment: It doesn't look like you're calling transaction correctly at all.  Consider experimenting with an extremely simple transaction handler to learn how they work first. You don't need Cloud Functions to do that - you can write a local node program to make it easier.
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference#transaction  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions

Comment: @DougStevenson ya i know how the basic transactions work and i am using them to update star count of the blog post

Comment: @DougStevenson and what part am i doing wrong in the transaction above

Comment: The transaction method takes three arguments.  As far as I can see, you're passing one argument.  Also you typically don't call set() inside a transactionUpdate callback, you just return when the data at the location should be.

Comment: @DougStevenson i use a set method to create a node if one does not exist already....ok could you provide any suggestion on how can i accomplish my usecase

Comment: You have a complicated case, and I'm not sure that a single database trigger is going to help you batch a series of events into a single notification that could happen over some amount of time.  You're going to have to first define exactly the conditions for when a batch should be sent, then apply that logic at the right time.  A database trigger might not even be the best way to do that.